# A lot of node errors after the Visual Studio Online build completed

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am trying to build ASP.NET project in Visual Studio Online, I managed to get the build itself, but on a prepublish step I have some gulp tasks to execute, but during some node operation the build generates a lot of errors like that:

> DNU (0, 0) ENOENT, lstat
>   'C:\a\1\s\Frontend\src\Frontend\node_modules\gulp-debug\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\load-json-file\node_modules\parse-json\vendor\unicode.js'
>
> DNU (0, 0) ENOENT, lstat
>   'C:\a\1\s\Frontend\src\Frontend\node_modules\gulp-concat\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\load-json-file\node_modules\strip-bom\node_modules\is-utf8\LICENSE'
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets
>   (156, 5) File exists:
>   C:\a\1\s\Frontend\src\Frontend\node_modules\gulp-debug\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\load-json-file\node_modules\pinkie-promise
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets
>   (156, 5) Move it away, and try again.
>
> DNU (0, 0) ENOENT, lstat
>   'C:\a\1\s\Frontend\src\Frontend\node_modules\gulp-filelogger\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\read-pkg\node_modules\load-json-file\node_modules\pinkie-promise\node_modules\pinkie\readme.md'
>
> DNU (0, 0) EPERM, unlink
>   'C:\a\1\s\Frontend\src\Frontend\node_modules\gulp-concat\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\loud-rejection\node_modules\signal-exit\test\fixtures\change-code-expect.json'
>
> DNU (0, 0) ENOENT, lstat
>   'C:\a\1\s\Frontend\src\Frontend\node_modules\gulp-concat\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\loud-rejection\node_modules\signal-exit\test\fixtures\change-code-expect.json'
>
> DNU (0, 0) EPERM, unlink
>   'C:\a\1\s\Frontend\src\Frontend\node_modules\gulp-debug\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\multipipe\node_modules\duplexer2\node_modules\readable-stream\float.patch'
>
> DNU (0, 0) ENOENT, lstat
>   'C:\a\1\s\Frontend\src\Frontend\node_modules\gulp-debug\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\multipipe\node_modules\duplexer2\node_modules\readable-stream\float.patch'

Comment: Does it actually cause the build to fail?

Comment: Does this issue always occur? I saw this issue once yesterday, but it does not occur anymore when I queue the build again.

Comment: The build itself does not fail I think, but I got no bundles, so the published site won't run, I'll try to see if this happens again now

Comment: I have verified I still get all of these errors, it seems I was able to build once, but it fails all other times... Is it some kind of an error with node installation? I have also added -NoNative for the DNX installation to save time on build, but that cannot affect the node.js errors I guess... (Plus you said you saw them as well)

Comment: What build agent are you using? Hosted or your own?

Comment: It's a hosted build agent, I did not install anything anywhere and use only what's provided by the platform.

Comment: Can you share the updated prebuild.ps1 that contain the changes to fix "System.Void" issue you have before?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I don't know how to attach files in comments (guess it's not possible), so I uploaded it to [pasteboard](http://pasteboard.co/L5KbdHQ.png). The two changes really are another higher level folder for dnu restore and added -NoNative to speed up the build, but I suppose thise cannot affect the node.js build?

Comment: I'm just using it to see if I can reproduce this issue, but didn't see it.

Comment: I have only npm in dependencies (removed bower), all of the nmp ones are for gulp, and this is my package.json:                  {
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-filelogger": "0.4.4",
    "gulp-debug": "2.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "1.8.0",
    "gulp-group-aggregate": "0.0.4",
    "gulp-copy": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-gzip": "1.2.0"
  }
}